# Ebean @Transactional annotation not working on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, ebean

I have a Play Framework 2.1.1 app running on Heroku.

I've written a bunch of new code in my local dev environment, and it works fine, but when I deploy it to Heroku the app crashes and I get this in the logs:

`Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot register class [models.Article] in Ebean server]
Oops, cannot start the server.
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/avaje/ebean/bean/EnhancedTransactional
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.avaje.ebean.bean.EnhancedTransactional
...
Process exited with status 255
State changed from starting to crashed`

When I remove the @Transactional annotations from my models, I no longer get the errors.

Here is an example of how I'm using @Transactional in one of my models:

`@Transactional
    public static Product find(Long id) {
        return find.byId(String.valueOf(id));
    }`

**Has anyone experienced this or have any idea why it works fine locally, but not in Heroku?**

Per request, here is my build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "myapp"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "8.4-702.jdbc4",
    "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1.0",
    "com.stripe" % "stripe-java" % "1.15.1",
    "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.3.11",
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  )

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to share your `build.sbt`? If not, can you open a ticket at http://help.heroku.com

Comment: I don't have a build.sbt

Comment: Do you have a `Build.scala`?

Comment: I added the build.scala to the question

Comment: So you just wanted to know if I had a Build.scala then?